# How to choose a processor in Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, terminal

I am using a Linux computer (Ubuntu) with n processors (15 as listed by /proc/cpuinfo). I have to run several applications and would like to run one in each processor. Is there a way to assign a processor to each application, or is it something that Linux does automatically?

Thank you very much

Comment: 15 is a funny number of CPUs, are you quite sure it's not 16 ?

Comment: You better leave the kernel chose the processors (actually the cores) for each process. Actually, the kernel will migrate (at will) processes from one core to another one.

Comment: Why do you ask? What exactly in the default behavior of Linux does not please you???

Comment: @cnicutar: You are right, I have 16 cores.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am timing several algorithms and wanted to save time and assign each of them to a parallel processor. But its really helpful to know that the kernel will migrate processes at will, thank you!

Comment: Don't bother at first. Just code using `pthreads` (or multiple processes with IPC). If you really measure that setting the affinity is helpful, do that. But it is just a tiny optimization. Make your parallel program correct at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [affinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity).

Linux should already handle this on its own, but there are ways of changing the affinity of a process (`sched_setaffinity`) and also the command line tool `taskset(1)`.

> taskset  is  used  to  set  or  retrieve  the CPU affinity of a
>   running process given its PID or to launch a  new  COMMAND  with  a 
>   given  CPU affinity.

Using `taskset` you can launch a process that will only become eligible to run on the cores you specify.

---

I'm not entirely sure they're the best tool for the job, but you might also want to investigate `cgroups`. I am almost certain they also allow pinning processes on certain CPUs.

Comment: Actually, you should avoid using `sched_setaffinity` unless you have a very good reason. The kernel will assign tasks to processors quite well in practice.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I completely agree. The scheduler already does a good job.